# Create new array from two array;

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two arrays

```
$views[] = $id; 
$pid[] = $page_id;
```

which prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 14
    [4] => 15
)
Array
(
    [0] => 174
    [1] => 221
    [2] => 174
    [3] => 174
    [4] => 174
)
```

now i want to create new array from this result like(first will be the key and second be the value)

```
Array
(
    [9] => 174
    [12] => 221
    [13] => 174
    [14] => 174
    [15] => 174
)
```

I have tired array_push function but didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)**:

> Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its
>   values

ie:

```
$newarr = array_combine($array1, $array2); //$array1: key, $array2: value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array1); $i++)
    $result[$array1[$i]] = $array2[i];
```